# Using Perl to iterate through a string 3 positions at a time

Tags: regex, string, perl, dna-sequence

I have written the following code in Perl. I want to iterate through a string 3 positions (characters) at a time. If `TAA`, `TAG`, or `TGA` (stop codons) appear, I want to print till the stop codons and remove the rest of the characters.

---

Example:

data.txt

> ATGGGTAATCCCTAGAAATTT
>
> ATGCCATTCAAGTAACCCTTT

Answer:

> ATGGGTAATCCCTAG (last 6 characters removed)
>
> ATGCCATTCAAGTAA (last 6 characters removed)

(Each sequence begins with ATG).

---

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

open FH, "data.txt";
@a=<FH>;

foreach $tmp(@a)
{
  for (my $i=0; $i<(length($tmp)-2); $i+=3)
  {
    if ($tmp=~/(ATG)(\w+)(TAA|TAG|TGA)\w+/)
    {
      print "$1$2$3\n";
    }
    else 
    { 
      print "$tmp\n"; 
    }
    $tmp++;
  }
}
exit;
```

However, my code is not giving the correct result. There should not be any overlaps in the characters (I want to move every 3 characters).

Can someone suggest how to fix the error?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to remove everything after the last of the stop codons, or do you want to remove everything after the first of the stop codons?

Comment: I want to remove everything after the first stop codon.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***Script:***

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open FH, "data.txt";
my @a = <FH>;

foreach (@a) {
  print /^(ATG(...)*?(TAA|TAG|TGA))/? $1 : $_, "\n";
}
```

***Output:***

```
ATGGGTAATCCCTAG
ATGCCATTCAAGTAA
```

Answer (score -2):

I think this code will do. It uses `\w{3}` - three-symbol codons as you need.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
open FH, "data.txt";
@a=<FH>;
foreach $tmp(@a) {
  if ($tmp=~ /^(ATG(?:\w{3})*(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)).*/) {
    print "$1\n";
  } else {
    print "$tmp\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: ...iterate through a string 3 positions (**characters**) at a time... `\w{3}` is not for any 3 characters

Answer (score -2):

You say you want to remove everything after the first stop codon. If so, all you need is

```
while (<FH>) {
   s/(?<=TAA|TAG|TGA).*//;
   print;
}
```

But then there's the mystical "I want to iterate through a string 3 positions (characters) at a time" requirement. That doesn't make any sense. Perhaps you want the match to occur at a position that's divisible by three? If so, you'd use

```
s/^(?:.{3})*?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)\K.*//;    # Requires 5.10+
s/^((?:.{3})*?(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)).*/$1/;  # Backwards compatible
```

Comment: ...iterate through a string **3** positions (characters) at a time... that `3` is what is important

Comment: @stackoverflow, The first pattern does look only three characters at a time. The second doesn't, because it's possible to match more than three characters by only looking at 3.

Comment: You updated your response, so now you see your mistake in original response :) Also - there is no need to use `?:` grouping, as you use just `$1` anyway...

Comment: @stackoverflow, Backwards. I do need to use grouping (`(?:)`); I don't require capturing (`()`) as well.

Comment: @stackoverflow, It's not a mistake to answer what was asked even if it's not the right answer. Acme::ESP doesn't always work.

Comment: `?:` is non-capturing **grouping**

Comment: @stackoverflow, I know, that's what I just said. Why?

Answer (score -2):

May I suggest a reading of [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Global-matching) (about 4 paragraphs down from here)?  It actually covers almost exactly this situation with avoiding overlaps and finding stop codons.